# ServerSelectionTimeoutError when trying to integrate Django with Apache

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, ubuntu

Basically I was following this instruction: http://thecodeship.com/deployment/deploy-django-apache-virtualenv-and-mod_wsgi/

But result is:

```
ServerSelectionTimeoutError at /admin/
```

No servers found yet

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://52.25.226.143/admin/
Django Version:     1.5.11
Exception Type:     ServerSelectionTimeoutError
Exception Value:

No servers found yet

Exception Location:     /home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py in select_servers, line 189
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:

['/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ubuntu/gitrepo/RIGIT/RIGIT_Backend',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 ...']

Server time:    Fri, 27 Jan 2017 20:05:17 -0600

Did I miss something simple?

Answer (score 0):

It was pymongodb bug, downgrade from 3.4 to 2.8. problem went away.